# Is there an easier way to chroot than bind-mounting?

Tags: chroot

Most of the time I use `chroot` to rescue an existing installation from usb.

When I `chroot` into another system I have to manually bind-mount `proc`, `sys`, `dev` and `dev/pts` by issuing for example:

```
mount --bind /proc proc/
```

Is there an **easy** way *already implemented* in a **standard** Ubuntu install?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See the schroot package.  [Man Page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/en/man1/schroot.1.html)

As an alternative, you can shorthand the bind mounting with:

```
for f in proc sys dev ; do mount --bind /$f /mnt/$f ; done
```

Comment: You could add references to the [manual page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/en/man1/schroot.1.html) and provide examples.

Comment: well... that's kindof why I asked about the _standard_ Ubuntu install. Of course there exist tools that do that. But is it as simple as sudo apt-get install schroot && schroot /dest ?

Comment: @turbo in that case, no.  One thing that can help save some typing though is rather than issue 3 separate bind mount commands, you can just do "for f in /sys /proc /dev ; do mount --bind $f /mnt/$f ; done"

Comment: yeah that's a good one. I knew and forgot about one line bash 'scripts'. I just seems kind of obvious from Ubuntu's point of view to include something like this in their rescue menu.

Comment: psusi if you change your answer to "for i in bla" I'm gonna accept this answer since that is what comes closest to answering my question, albeit being ... not 100% satisfying. Oh and don't forget /dev/pts please!

Comment: @Lenensteyn neat, good idea.

Comment: @turbo /dev/pts is part of /dev, so you don't need to treat it separately.

Comment: @turbo, @psusi `--bind` only mounts the specific named filesystem; it won't include `pts` or for that matter `shm`.  However if you use [`mount --rbind`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/en/man2/mount.2.html) it will work.

Comment: ah cool! good one! It's funny that every how-to on earth suggests          <code>mount --bind</code> ;)

Comment: @poolie I'll be damned... I guess you should use rbind then

Comment: @poolie actually it looks like --rbind is still a little buggy; you can't umount the rbind point.  I also have never run into anything that needed pts or shm, so...

Comment: @psusi, you'll probably need to manually umount the things inside it before you can unmount /dev.  If that doesn't work, yes, it's a bug.  `screen` would be an example of something that needs a pseudoterminal from `/dev/pts`, though it might fall back to putting them just under `/dev/`.