# Admin users on an Ubuntu Core installation

Tags: users, sudo, administrator, ubuntu-core

I installed Ubuntu Core using [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67001/what-commands-are-needed-to-install-ubuntu-core), and added a user. But when I try to add the user to the admin group, it says the group does not exist. What do I do?

**PS** I had to install `sudo`, however it made no difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On traditional Linux/Unix systems there is no "admin" group, such group was widely introduced for desktop usage.
If you really need an admin group on a core system (you may not needed), you will need to create it manually:

```
groupadd admin -g 120
```

Comment: Then if do not have my user in the admin group, how will do the tasks that require admin privileges? Log in as root?

Comment: (and I do need it since I'm just experimenting with my own desktop computer)

Comment: No, you install sudo and set it up allowing commands from a user/group. Anyway I gave you the answer how to create the group, if you really need it :)

Comment: According to this link: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/policykit-1/+bug/893842 Ubuntu now uses the 'sudo' group as the admin one. Therefore if you want to perform admin actions, your user will require to join the 'sudo' group.