# Ubuntu core keeps logging me out after successful login

Tags: ubuntu-core

I installed ubuntu core following this tutorial:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Core/InstallationExample

I tried these kernels

```
linux-image-3.2.0-58-generic-pae_3.2.0-58.88_i386
linux-image-3.2.0-23-generic-pae_3.2.0-23.36_i386
```

With their dependencies

```
libnl-3-200_3.2.3-2ubuntu2_i386
libnl-genl-3-200_3.2.3-2ubuntu2_i386
wireless-regdb_2011.04.28-1ubuntu3_all
crda_1.1.2-1ubuntu1_i386
wireless-crda_1.16_i386
```

The FS i used

```
ubuntu-core-12.04.3-core-i386.tar.gz
```

I did this on a virtual machine running on vmware esxi 5.1.0 with 1 GB RAM

I tried adding a user without the adm/sudo group, but I get logged out with that one too.

Also edited /etc/network/interfaces to

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp
```

But the dhcp server doesen't show any dhcp request

I also installed rsyslog but the auth.log is empty.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Running

```
chmod go+rx /
```

while chrooted solved the login error. Still trying to fix the network.

Thanks to Alex! [What commands are needed to install Ubuntu Core?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67001/what-commands-are-needed-to-install-ubuntu-core/70139#comment283691_70139)