# What Happened to Ubuntu Core (RootFS)?

Tags: ubuntu-core

I was planning to use the Ubuntu Core RootFS (NOT SNAPPY) for a POC at work - but it seems the wiki entries and subpages are gone!!!

Does anyone know if Canonical has abandoned this???

Here's a few previously relevant links (they're dead now):

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Core 
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Core/InstallationExample

Comment: Here is a few more previously relevant links (not dead):

http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-core
http://askubuntu.com/questions/67001/what-commands-are-needed-to-install-ubuntu-core
http://linux-exynos.org/wiki/Installing_a_rootfs
https://github.com/umiddelb/armhf/wiki/Install-Ubuntu-Core-14.04-on-ARMv7-(ODROID-C1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it's been renamed to `ubuntu-base`, which can be found [here](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-base/).

Comment: That seems to be the case. I had a small heart attack when the wiki disappeared. Relevant wiki is here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Base

It would have been nice of Canonical to just link the old wiki page to the new one.

Thanks James!!!

Comment: Even nicer would have been if they hadn't changed the name. I'm going to guess we have marketing to thank for this?