# How to install Ubuntu Base?

Tags: 20.04, ubuntu-minimal

Is there a guide to install Ubuntu Base?

Id like to set up Ubuntu Base 20.04
http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-base/releases/20.04/release/

Comment: Installing from [mini.iso](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/installer-amd64/current/legacy-images/netboot/mini.iso) is more user-friendly, IMHO.

Comment: For Base install details see https://askubuntu.com/questions/67001/what-commands-are-needed-to-install-ubuntu-core

Comment: I totally agree that mini.iso is easier and thats what I have been using. But, as mini.iso is now officially considered legacy, I thought i'd try out Base and learn a little.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The guide is at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Base

- WARNING: Ubuntu Base is NOT a normal, user-friendly, easy-to-install form of Ubuntu. Unskilled users should stick to the normal installers. If you don't understand the requirements or procedure below, then Ubuntu Base is probably the wrong choice for you.

> Deploying Base Requirements
>
> - Ubuntu Base rootfs
> - Linux kernel for target device
> - Boot-loader for target device
>
> Procedure:
>
> 1. Format target media: at least one partition should be ext2, ext3, or
>    ext4
> 2. Unpack Ubuntu Base to ext{2,3,4} partition
> 3. Install boot-loader
> 4. Install Linux
> 5. Add a local user and password for the user, then add the
>    user to the adm and sudo groups
> 6. If the Linux kernel requires modules,
>    add these to /lib/modules/$(uname -r) in the ext{2,3,4} file system
> 7. Boot the target device
> 8. Install any additional required software using apt-get