# Do we have a Ubuntu Base image that we can use for creating a custom ISO?

Tags: iso, ubuntu-core, custom-distributions

Need to create a custom ISO using Ubuntu Base image but I am unable to find one for the same.
Can someone please help me find the Ubuntu Base image and also CLI method of creating an ISO from it ?

Comment: http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-base/releases/20.04/release/

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: Add the bootloader, kernel, filesystem, and your other customizations. See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Base and https://askubuntu.com/a/70139/19626

Step 2: Wrap your system into a .iso image. See https://wiki.debian.org/RepackBootableISO

Step 3: Test, debug, repeat.

Ubuntu Base is an informal project that Canonical engineers use to simplify their various cloud and specialty-hardware projects to provide a uniform Ubuntu experience.

It is not a "real" flavor of Ubuntu. It is not intended to replace the discontinued Netinstall (Minimal) image. It is not designed for easy installation by normal users who can boot PC Hardware from a USB port.

Generally, folks who need to ask "*how do I...*" about Ubuntu Base should avoid Ubuntu Base; use a more appropriate tool or workflow for your skill level instead.