# Encrypted drive (full disk encryption) gone after upgrade to 14.04

Tags: boot, 14.04, upgrade, encryption, disk

I'm in a bit of a pickle. I have just done an upgrade from 13.10 to 14.04, then I rebooted the machine and now the drive/partition is gone, so it boots into memtest.

The drive was encrypted during installation (13.04) using full disk encryption. The update to 13.10 went without issues.

If I use a LiveUSB I can mount the drive just fine, so I assume it's a GRUB problem, but I can't really figure out what's wrong. Does anyone know a way to make the disk visible again from a LiveUSB?

The computer is a Lenovo X1 Carbon, so the SSD is non-removable (The SSD is visible in the BIOS).

Answer (score 0):

If you can mount the drive from the live CD, I would set up a `chroot` environment, and then chroot into the partition. Then, you can use `update-grub` or similar to fix grub. I assume you mount your cryptfs into `/mnt/` and you use grub.

**Setting up chroot**

Taken from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32418/is-there-an-easier-way-to-chroot-than-bind-mounting/32426#32426), run as root:

```
for f in proc sys dev ; do mount --bind /$f /mnt/$f ; done
```

To set up the /dev/proc etc.

**Starting the chroot**

```
sudo chroot /mnt
```

**Repair Grub**

```
update-grub
```

That should update your grub setup. After that you are all done, reboot.

If that does not work, we need more detail on your grub configuration and partitions.

Comment: The update of grub worked fine, but unfortunately it didn't solve the problem. I really appreciate the answer, but my solution in the end was just to copy what I needed to my server, and install a fresh 14.04.

Comment: @user3592047 Sure, also good. Have fun with the X1, I also have one :)