# "Kernel panic, VFs:unable to mount root fs on unknown block(0,0)" after ugrade to 18.04

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, grub2, kernel

In the past I used to be able to dual-boot Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 10 on a SSD and it worked like a charm.

Finishing upgrade to 18.04 ubuntu asked me to update grub which I did recklessly and ended up with the following error:

> Kernel panic, VFs:unable to mount root fs on unknown block(0,0)

I believe I have already tried all that's been suggested on the site, to no avail I.E.:

- boot-repair
- grub rescue
- updating initramfs via live CD and chroot,
- tried removing some of the old images on root to open up space, enabled and disabled secure boot in bios,
- ...

As per the Boot Repair SOP, I'm posting my current Boot info [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/3f6d2MxwKT/)

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: You installed 16.04 in MBR/BIOS mode under 16.04 whereas W10 was in UEFI mode.  The upgrade got confused and now 18.04 doesn't boot any more, so the best thing you can do is to take a full system backup and re-install 18.04 in UEFI mode as this issue will otherwise continue to follow you around.

Comment: Are you able to boot to a prior/older Ubuntu kernel? Are you able to boot into Recovery Mode?

Comment: @heynnema under grub menu I can see 4.13.0-38 and 37 plus their recovery mode, no matter which I choose, I end up with the same error.

Comment: @Fabby I went ahead with the upgrade boldly, that is to say without backing up, now I know I can recover my files, but will I be able to recover installed packages and installed programs after a fresh install? is there a way to do a full system backup through live cd etc? also thank you for tidying up my post

Comment: Recover data: yes.  Recover packages: more or less: You can [list installed packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17823/how-to-list-all-installed-packages) but as you've got a system that cannot boot, you have to boot from a live USB and [chroot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32418/is-there-an-easier-way-to-chroot-than-bind-mounting) first.  That's complicated and if those two answers don't help you, better manually install packages again.